# java.util.Date to java.sql.Date conversion gives wrong month

Tags: java, date, jdbc

Consider the following snippet:

```
Calendar futureDate = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = 2011;
int month = 11;
int day = 14;
futureDate.set(year,month, day);
System.out.println(futureDate.toString());
java.sql.Date sqlDate  = new java.sql.Date( futureDate.getTime().getTime());
```

The printout from futureDate.toString() is:

.....YEAR=2011,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=43,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=14,DAY_OF_YEAR=289,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=0,HOUR=11,HOUR_OF_DAY=11,MINUTE=32,SECOND=51,MILLISECOND=117,ZONE_OFFSET=-18000000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]

which shows that the Calendare object holds the correct date.  However, after converting to sql date and storing in the database (MySQL through JDBC), the MySQL table shows '2011-12-14' for this date instead of '2011-11-14'.
I would have suspected locale and time zone, but these would cause discrepancy in the time of day not in the month part of the date.

Any clues to what I did wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Calendar#set(int, int, int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set%28int,%20int,%20int%29) interprets the month argument as zero-based, so `futureDate.set(2011, 11, 14)` sets the calendar's month to December.

Comment: Please use the intended constants for it, e.g. futureDate.set(2011,Calendar.DECEMBER,14)

Comment: Thanks.  That must be it. I can't use Calendar.NOVEMBER because the value comes from an input field, but now I now to adjust for zero based month values.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2011 , 11 , 14 )  // November 14th, 2011
```

## Details

The Answer by Matt Ball is correct. But now there is a much improved way.

## java.time

The troublesome old date-time classes such as `Calendar`, `java.util.Date`, and `java.sql.Date` are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Unlike the legacy classes, the java.time classes have **sane numbering**, such as months being numbered **1-12 for January to December**, and 1-7 for Monday to Sunday.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2011 , 11 , 14 ) ;
```

Or use the handy [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2011 , Month.NOVEMBER , 14 ) ;
```

With a JDBC driver supporting JDBC 4.2 and later, you may pass your java.time objects directly to the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

When fetching, use `getObject`.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).